# Infinitely many squares of the form $3a^2 + 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

I am working on the following proof.

> Prove that $3a^2 + 1$ (as $a$ ranges over the integers) produces infinitely many squares.

*Proof:*

We first note that all square numbers can be represented as $3k, 3k+1, 3k+2$.

Cases:

(i) $3a^2+1=3k \rightarrow a^2-k=\frac{-1}{3} \rightarrow 3 \nmid -1$, thus we conclude that $3a^2+1$ will not produce squares of the form $3k$.

(ii) $3a^2+1=3k+1 \rightarrow a^2-k=0 \rightarrow 3 \mid 0$, thus we conclude that $3a^2+1$ will produce squares of the form $3k+1$ given $a^2=k$.

(iii) $3a^2+1=3k+2 \rightarrow a^2-k=\frac{1}{3} \rightarrow 3 \nmid 1$, thus we conclude that $3a^2+1$ will not produce squares of the form $3k+2$.

Case (ii) is the only case where $3a^2+1$ will produce a square number. I think I should be able to make the conclusion that since $a^2=k$, $3a^2+1$ will produce infinitely many squares, but I am not confident on the conclusion.

I examined a couple of numbers and found that:

$a=4 \rightarrow k=16=4^2$

$a=15 \rightarrow k=225=15^2$

I am not positive on where to go from here, a hint would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I.e. prove that the equation $x^2-3a^2=1$ has infinitely many integer solutions $(x,a)$. This is one of the [Pell's Equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation): all equations of the form $x^2-ny^2=1$, where $n\in\mathbb Z^+$ is fixed and not a square, have infinitely many integer solutions $(x,y)$.

Comment: Hi, please always make your titles as specific as possible! Also, you can use `*italic text*` to make *italic text*, rather than using dollar signs which are for math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$q^2-3a^2 = 1 $$
is a [Pell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation) with infinitely many solutions, since $q^2-3a^2$ is the norm of $q+a\sqrt{3}$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ and $2+\sqrt{3}$ has unit norm, so $(2+\sqrt{3})^n$ also has unit norm. If we start with the fundamental solutions $(q_0,a_0)=(1,0)$ and $(q_1,a_1)=(2,1)$ it follows that the sequences
$$ \{q_n\}=\{1,2,7,26,\ldots\},\qquad \{a_n\}=\{0,1,4,15,\ldots\} $$
with characteristic polynomial $x^2-4x+1$ give an infinite number of solutions $(q_n,a_n)$.

Comment: Given ${q_n}$ and ${a_n}$, can we find a recursive relation? My thought is that I need to find $m,n,u,v$ such that $ma+nb=2$ and $ua+vb=1$. I am not quite sure how to continue.

Comment: @Joseph: the characteristic polynomial gives the recurrence $$q_{n+2} = 4 q_{n+1} - q_n. $$ The same recurrence holds for $\{a_n\}$.

Comment: How is it that the same recurrence holds for  ${a_n}$? When checking the relation it does not hold.

Comment: $$ q_n+a_n\sqrt{3} = (2+\sqrt{3})^n $$ gives that the vectors $(q_n,a_n)$ are given by $M^n(1,0)$ for some matrix, hence the characteristic polynomial of the two sequences has to be the same, namely the characteristic polynomial of $M$, $x^2-4x+1$.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose there is one solution $x^2=3a^2+1$.  Then $(x^2-3a^2)(x^2-3a^2)=1 \implies$ $$(x^2+3a^2)^2-3(2ax)^2=1$$ is another solution when you set

$x'=x^2+3a^2$

$a'=2ax$

Note that $x'>x$ and $a'>a$ for $a, x>0$

---

To see at least one solution exists, just take $x=2, a=1$.